# What the difference = pointers

Tags: c, pointers

What the difference between:

```
int x = (int *)7;
```

to:

```
int x = 7;
```

thanks

Comment: One will compile and the other won't, at least not without warnings?

Comment: Warnings which are supposed to be errors, per the C standard.

Comment: is this some sort of prank you are playing on compiler?? :D

Answer (score 4):

First of all the first line is invalid. You can't assign a pointer to an int (which is to say, you really shouldn't. It is allowed, but it makes no sense).

However, the difference is that `(int*)7` means "the integer at address 7", and `7` just means 7.

Comment: `*(int *) 7` means "the integer at address 7"; `(int *) 7` just means "address 7".

Comment: @John Bode: yes but the fact that it's an `int*` and not a `void*` means that the pointer somehow indicates what type it's pointing at. So even though it's "address 7", we also know it's an int.

Answer (score 3):

```
(int *)
```

WARNING: humourous answer

Comment: +1 it's better than most of the answers here...

Answer (score 1):

The first one will cause a compiler error as you are assigning a pointer to an int.  Pointers (especially in 64-bit land) are not equivilent to integers.

The exact answer is the first is assigning a pointer with the address of 7 to an int, the second is just assigning an int.

Comment: Nope, gcc gives me a warning only.

Comment: That's an intentional bug in gcc.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a practical difference, because in the first example the 7 is explicitly cast to an int *, and then implicitly cast to an int to match x's type.  However, the first example is "Bad Code" because it is confusing.

Comment: It's also invalid C. C does not allow implicit conversions from pointer to integer types or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is valid C that initializes an `int` variable `x` with the value 7.

The former is a compile-time error, which many compilers will erroneously ignore. You cannot assign a pointer to an integer variable.

Comment: Why can't an integer variable be assigned to a pointer?  If I have an address value in an integer, I'd like to assign it to a pointer.  I have done this in embedded systems, with a flat address space.

Comment: You can cast it but you cannot assign it directly. The C language does not allow direct assignment between integer types and pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is wrong and you should get a warning - at least- from your compiler.  Something of type `(int *)` shouldn't be assigned to `int`.

Comment: You should get an error, not a warning, but compilers are usually wrong in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The first example stores an address in an integer, which is not type safe, is not really valid (and will break on a lot of platforms).  That you chose an address which has the same byte representation as the number seven is happenstance.  You could have easily chosen another address, including one that can't fit into an "int" data type.

The second example stores an integer in an integer, which is valid.

Every accessible memory chunk has an address, and a pointer is nothing except the number associated with that address.  If you want to "walk through the address" properly in the first example, it would have been something like this:

```
int x = *(&7);
(int x equals the contents of the address where the number seven is stored)
```

Unfortunately, the above won't compile either, as C lacks the concept of taking the address of a constant not associated with a name.